# Python Class definition and function

Tags: python, object

```
class RESTAPI():
    def __init__(self, client, path):
        self.client = client
        self.path = path

    def sendRequest(self, method, path):
        return self.client.sendRequest(method, self.path + path)
```

In this case, the class of RESTAPI, I couldn't see where its client object defining its sendRequest method.

Here's the complete code

```
from webiopi.utils import LOGGER, PYTHON_MAJOR, encodeCredentials
from webiopi.protocols.coap import COAPClient, COAPGet, COAPPost, COAPPut, COAPDelete

if PYTHON_MAJOR >= 3:
    import http.client as httplib
else:
    import httplib

class PiMixedClient():
    def __init__(self, host, port=8000, coap=5683):
        self.host = host
        if coap > 0:
            self.coapport = coap
            self.coapclient = COAPClient()
        else:
            self.coapclient = None
        if port > 0:
            self.httpclient = httplib.HTTPConnection(host, port)
        else:
            self.httpclient = None
        self.forceHttp = False
        self.coapfailure = 0
        self.maxfailure = 2
        self.auth= None;

    def setCredentials(self, login, password):
        self.auth = "Basic " + encodeCredentials(login, password)

def sendRequest(self, method, uri):
    if self.coapclient != None and not self.forceHttp:
        if method == "GET":
            response = self.coapclient.sendRequest(COAPGet("coap://%s:%d%s" % (self.host, self.coapport, uri)))
        elif method == "POST":
            response = self.coapclient.sendRequest(COAPPost("coap://%s:%d%s" % (self.host, self.coapport, uri)))

        if response:
            return str(response.payload)
        elif self.httpclient != None:
            self.coapfailure += 1
            print("No CoAP response, fall-back to HTTP")
            if (self.coapfailure > self.maxfailure):
                self.forceHttp = True
                self.coapfailure = 0
                print("Too many CoAP failure forcing HTTP")

    if self.httpclass RESTAPI():
def __init__(self, client, path):
    self.client = client
    self.path = path

def sendRequest(self, method, path):
    return self.client.sendRequest(method, self.path + path) != None:
        headers = {}
        if self.auth != None:
            headers["Authorization"] = self.auth

        self.httpclient.request(method, uri, None, headers)
        response = self.httpclient.getresponse()
        if response.status == 200:
            data = response.read()
            return data
        elif response.status == 401:
            raise Exception("Missing credentials")
        else:
            raise Exception("Unhandled HTTP Response %d %s" % (response.status, response.reason))

    raise Exception("No data received")

class PiHttpClient(PiMixedClient):
    def __init__(self, host, port=8000):
        PiMixedClient.__init__(self, host, port, -1)

class PiCoapClient(PiMixedClient):
    def __init__(self, host, port=5683):
        PiMixedClient.__init__(self, host, -1, port)

class PiMulticastClient(PiMixedClient):
    def __init__(self, port=5683):
        PiMixedClient.__init__(self, "224.0.1.123", -1, port)

class RESTAPI():
    def __init__(self, client, path):
        self.client = client
        self.path = path

    def sendRequest(self, method, path):
        return self.client.sendRequest(method, self.path + path)

class Macro(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        RESTAPI.__init__(self, client, "/macros/" + name + "/")

    def call(self, *args):
        values = ",".join(["%s" % i for i in args])
        if values == None:
            values = ""
        return self.sendRequest("POST", values)

class Device(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, client, name, category):
        RESTAPI.__init__(self, client, "/devices/" + name + "/" + category)

class GPIO(Device):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        Device.__init__(self, client, name, "digital")

    def getFunction(self, channel):
        return self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/function" % channel)

    def setFunction(self, channel, func):
        return self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/function/%s" % (channel, func))

    def digitalRead(self, channel):
        return int(self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/value" % channel))

    def digitalWrite(self, channel, value):
        return int(self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/value/%d" % (channel, value)))

    def portRead(self):
        return int(self.sendRequest("GET", "/integer"))

    def portWrite(self, value):
        return int(self.sendRequest("POST", "/integer/%d" % value))

class NativeGPIO(GPIO):
    def __init__(self, client):
        RESTAPI.__init__(self, client, "/GPIO")

class ADC(Device):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        Device.__init__(self, client, name, "analog")

    def read(self, channel):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/integer" % channel))

    def readFloat(self, channel):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/float" % channel))

    def readVolt(self, channel):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/volt" % channel))

class DAC(ADC):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        Device.__init__(self, client, name, "analog")

    def write(self, channel, value):
        return float(self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/integer/%d" % (channel, value)))

    def writeFloat(self, channel, value):
        return float(self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/float/%f" % (channel, value)))

    def writeVolt(self, channel, value):
        return float(self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/volt/%f" % (channel, value)))

class PWM(DAC):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        Device.__init__(self, client, name, "pwm")

    def readAngle(self, channel, value):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/%d/angle" % (channel)))

    def writeAngle(self, channel, value):
        return float(self.sendRequest("POST", "/%d/angle/%f" % (channel, value)))

class Sensor(Device):
    def __init__(self, client, name):
        Device.__init__(self, client, name, "sensor")

class Temperature(Sensor):
    def getKelvin(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/temperature/k"))

    def getCelsius(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/temperature/c"))

    def getFahrenheit(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/temperature/f"))

class Pressure(Sensor):
    def getPascal(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/pressure/pa"))

    def getHectoPascal(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/pressure/hpa"))

class Luminosity(Sensor):
    def getLux(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/luminosity/lux"))

class Distance(Sensor):
    def getMillimeter(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/distance/mm"))

    def getCentimeter(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/distance/cm"))

    def getInch(self):
        return float(self.sendRequest("GET", "/distance/in"))
```

Comment: `client` is an entirely different object, so it would be helpful to see the source code for the client class, rather then the source code for `RESTAPI`.

Comment: Do you have the entire source code for whatever software or program this is from? Try looking for `client` then. If you're a developer and you don't have access to the source code, then look for the `documentation`. You might not need to know the actual function definition.

Comment: I don't know where's the client object is defined. I posted the entire code for that module and couldn't find client

Comment: What everybody is saying is that this code must be part of something bigger, because there is no call to any of the methods.  
Look in the code that actually creates an instance of the `RESTAPI` class, and you will see that at the argument "client" you will find an object that supports the method `sendRequest`.

Comment: If there is none, and this is the only code provided, then chances are that `COAPclient` might contain what you need...

Comment: there's no instance of RESTAPI only subclass it class Device(RESTAPI):
   and I don't see client and the COAPclient relationship.